# Longest expected head streak in 200 coinflips

Tags: python, python-2.7, mean, coin-flipping

I was trying to calculate the expected value for the longest consecutive heads streak in 200 coin flips, using python. I came up with a code which I think does the job right but it's just not efficient because of the amount of calculations and data storage it requires, and I was wondering if someone could help me out with this, making it faster and more efficient (I took only one course of python programming in last semester without any previous knowledge of the subject).

My code was

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import permutations

counter = 0
sett = 0
rle = []

matrix = np.zeros(200)

for i in range (0,200):
    matrix[i] = 1
    for j in permutations(matrix):
        for k in j:
            if k == 1:
               counter += 1
            else:
               if counter > sett:
                  sett == counter
               counter == 0
        rle.append(sett)
```

After finding rle, I'd iterate over it to get how many streaks of which length there are, and their sum divided by 2^200 would give me the expected value I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance for help, much appreciated!

Comment: You have 200! (almost 8e374) permutations for each of your matrices, so your whole life won't be enough to try them all. You'd better try a completely different approach!

Comment: Does expected value of longest streak refer to the most probable number of consecutive heads you get?

Comment: I still don't see what is wrong in my answer but I'll read about it. For now I have removed my answer.

Comment: I think I get what was wrong. I was solving a different question altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to try all the permutations (in fact you cannot), but you can do a simple Monte Carlo style simulation. Repeat the 200 coin flips many times. Average the lengths of longest streaks you get and this will be a good approximation of the expected value.

```
def oneTrial (noOfCoinFlips):
    s = numpy.random.binomial(1, 0.5, noOfCoinFlips)
    maxCount = 0
    count = 0
    for x in s:
        if x == 1:
            count += 1
        if x == 0:
            count = 0
        maxCount = max(maxCount, count)
    return maxCount


numpy.mean([oneTrial(200) for x in range(10000)])

Output: 6.9843
```

Also see [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1409372/what-is-the-expected-length-of-the-largest-run-of-heads-if-we-make-1-000-flips) for exact computation without using Python simulation.

Answer (score 0):

*This is an answer to a slightly different question. But, as I had invested an hour and half of my time into it, I didn't wanna scrape it off.*

Let `E(k)` denote a `k` head streak, i.e., you get `k` consecutive heads from the **first toss onwards**.

```
E(0): T { another 199 tosses that we do not care about }
E(1): H T { another 198 tosses... }
.
.
E(198): { 198 heads } T H
E(199): { 199 heads } T
E(200): { 200 heads }
```

Note that `P(0) = 0.5`, which is `P(tails in first toss)`
whereas `P(1) = 0.25` , i.e., `P(heads in first toss and tails in the second)`

```
P(0) = 2**-1
P(1) = 2**-2
.
.
.
P(198) = 2**-199
P(199) = 2**-200
P(200) = 2**-200    #same as P(199)
```

Which means if you toss a coin `2**200` times, you'd get

```
E(0) 2**199 times
E(1) 2**198 times
.
.
E(198) 2**1 times
E(199) 2**0 times and
E(200) 2**0 times.
```

Thus, the expected value reduces to

```
(0*(2**199) + 1*(2**198) + 2*(2**197) + ... + 198*(2**1) + 199*(2**0) + 200*(2**0))/2**200
```

This number is virtually equal to 1.

```
Expected_value = 1 - 2**-200
```

How I got the difference.

```
>>> diff = 2**200 - sum([ k*(2**(199-k)) for k in range(200)], 200*(2**0))
>>> diff
1
```

This can be generalized to `n` tosses as

```
f(n) = 1 - 2**(-n)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The OP is looking for the [expected value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) of the length of the longest streak.

Comment: doesn't expected value mean the one with greatest probability? @das-g

Comment: No, not the value with greatest probability, in statistics, that's a fixed term to refer to the limit of the average if you repeat the random experiment indefinitely.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what question this is answering, but I'm pretty sure that the expectation value for the maximum length of a head streak in 200 coin tosses is greater than one..

Comment: Wouldn't considering the ideal case give the closest result? I assumed the event to be ideal, i.e., if the coin is tossed 200 times, all the `2**200` possibilities will occur.

Comment: I get it. This is a different question altogether, +1 to @das-g 's first comment. :P